# How to reset identity in Table

Tags: c#, sql

My scenario is... I create Table as(id identity(1,1) not null,name varchar(500),category varchar(50))... i try to insert values.. displays has (1,'sede','diabetes') and it goes has 1,2,3. But when i delete the total content.. once again insert it starts with 4,5,6...

I don want this type of inserting...When content i deleted it should start from 1,2,3..

How can i achieve this.. i need it in stored procedure.. Any idea..

Comment: Why do you need this? What is the problem with having "spaces" in the identity field?

Comment: @Oded, it's a long time after your comment and I didn't post this question, but in my case I want to reset the identity so I can write unit tests (using tst.codeplex.com). I populate tables with relevant data before each test, some of which have identity columns. TST wraps each test in a transaction which is rolled back after the test runs, but it doesn't reset identities so the identity in subsequent tests increments from previous ones. It makes it easier to write tests if the identity doesn't change between each run.

Answer (score 7):

You can reset the Identity seed by executing [dbcc checkident](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx)

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ("TableName", RESEED, 0)
```

Comment: on a regular basis? Resetting all IDs when one is deleted?

Comment: @Oded - No, I wouldn't recommend doing this after every delete.  I was under the impression that the delete was a one off or infrequent.  Maybe @Shiny could clarify.