# Auto running number ID with format xxxx/year number (9999/12) in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have one table (`Stock_ID, Stock_Name`). I want to write a stored procedure in SQL Server with `Stock_ID` running number with a format like `xxxx/12` (`xxxx` = number start from 0001 to 9999; `12` is the last 2 digits of current year).

My scenario is that if the year change, the running number will be reset to `0001/13`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Stock_ID INT,Stock_Name VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @tbl
SELECT 1,'Test'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Test2'

DECLARE @ShortDate VARCHAR(2)=RIGHT(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)),2)

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY tbl.Stock_ID) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS RowNbr,
        tbl.Stock_ID,
        tbl.Stock_Name
    FROM
        @tbl AS tbl
)
SELECT
    REPLICATE('0', 4-LEN(RowNbr))+CTE.RowNbr+'/'+@ShortDate AS YourColumn,
    CTE.Stock_ID,
    CTE.Stock_Name
FROM
    CTE
```

Answer (score 2):

what do you intend to do when you hit more than 9999 in a single year???  it may sound impossible, but I've had to deal with so many "it will never happen" data related design mess-ups over the years from code first design later developers.  These are major pains depending on how may places you need to fix these items which are usually primary key and foreign keys used all over.

This looks like a system requirement to SHOW the data this way, but it is the developers responsibility to design the internals of the application.  The way you store it and display it don't need to be identical.  I'd split that into two columns, using an int for the number portion and a tiny int for the 2 digit year portion.  You can use a computed column for quick and easy display (persist it and index if necessary), where you pad with leading zeros and add the slash.  Throw in a check constraint on the year portion to make sure it stays within a reasonable range.  You can make the number portion an identity and just have a job reseed it back to 1 every new years eve.

try it out:

```
--drop table YourTable

--create the basic table
CREATE TABLE YourTable
(YourNumber int identity(1,1) not null
,YourYear tinyint not null
,YourData varchar(10)
,CHECK (YourYear>=12 and YourYear<=25) --optional check constraint
)

--add the persisted computed column
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD YourFormattedNumber AS ISNULL(RIGHT('0000'+CONVERT(varchar(10),YourNumber),4)+'/'+RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(10),YourYear),2),'/') PERSISTED

--make the persisted computed column the primary key
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD CONSTRAINT PK_YourTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (YourFormattedNumber)
```

sample data:

```
--insert rows in 2012
insert into YourTable values (12,'aaaa')
insert into YourTable values (12,'bbbb')
insert into YourTable values (12,'cccc')

--new years eve job run this
DBCC CHECKIDENT (YourTable, RESEED, 0)   

--insert rows in 2013
insert into YourTable values (13,'aaaa')
insert into YourTable values (13,'bbbb')

select * from YourTable order by YourYear,YourNumber
```

OUTPUT:

```
YourNumber  YourYear YourData   YourFormattedNumber
----------- -------- ---------- -------------------
1           12       aaaa       0001/12
2           12       bbbb       0002/12
3           12       cccc       0003/12
1           13       aaaa       0001/13
2           13       bbbb       0002/13

(5 row(s) affected)
```

to handle the possibility of more than 9999 rows per year try a different computed column calculation:

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable
(YourNumber int identity(9998,1) not null  --<<<notice the identity starting point, so it hits 9999 quicker for this simple test
,YourYear tinyint not null
,YourData varchar(10)
)

--handles more than 9999 values per year
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD YourFormattedNumber AS ISNULL(RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',CASE WHEN LEN(CONVERT(varchar(10),YourNumber))<4 THEN 4 ELSE 1 END)+CONVERT(varchar(10),YourNumber),CASE WHEN LEN(CONVERT(varchar(10),YourNumber))<4 THEN 4 ELSE LEN(CONVERT(varchar(10),YourNumber)) END)+'/'+RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(10),YourYear),2),'/') PERSISTED

ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD CONSTRAINT PK_YourTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (YourFormattedNumber)
```

sample data:

```
insert into YourTable values (12,'aaaa')
insert into YourTable values (12,'bbbb')
insert into YourTable values (12,'cccc')

DBCC CHECKIDENT (YourTable, RESEED, 0)   --new years eve job run this

insert into YourTable values (13,'aaaa')
insert into YourTable values (13,'bbbb')

select * from YourTable order by YourYear,YourNumber
```

OUTPUT:

```
YourNumber  YourYear YourData   YourFormattedNumber
----------- -------- ---------- --------------------
9998        12       aaaa       9998/12
9999        12       bbbb       9999/12
10000       12       cccc       10000/12
1           13       aaaa       0001/13
2           13       bbbb       0002/13

(5 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: another thought, you can just drop the column to store the 2 digit year (`YourYear` column in the sample code) if you have a create date column in the table, just use: `RIGHT(CONVERT(char(4),YEAR(CreateDate)),2)` in the computed column definition in place of the `YourYear` column.

Comment: thanks KM. i'v tried out your comment and result is that: the running number was not reset when the year changed. here are the result
YourNumber YourYear YourData YourFormattedNumber
1 12 test 0001/12
2 12 test1 0002/12
3 13 test2 0003/13
4 13 test3 0004/13
5 14 test5 0005/14

I've estimated the data already, it never run over 9999 per year. anyway thanks for your helpful idea.

Comment: @sokea, I'm not sure what you did wrong, but resetting an identity column is fairly simple, see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3108771/65223

Answer (score 1):

From memory, this is a way to get the next id:

```
declare @maxid int
select @maxid = 0

-- if it does not have @maxid will be 0, if it was it will give the next id
select @maxid = max(convert(int, substring(Stock_Id, 1, 4))) + 1
from table
where substring(Stock_Id, 6, 2) = substring(YEAR(getdate()), 3, 2)


declare @nextid varchar(7)
select @nextid = right('0000'+ convert(varchar,@maxid),4)) + '/' + substring(YEAR(getdate()), 3, 2)
```

Comment: What if two connections try to get the max id at the same time?

Comment: Thanks aF. I've test by create new stored procedure, When Execute, I got the error:

Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Procedure test_add, Line 10
Argument data type int is invalid for argument 1 of substring function.
Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Procedure test_add, Line 15
Argument data type int is invalid for argument 1 of substring function.

Any help comment please?

Comment: Try it nw, there was a `)` missing!